# Intellij cannot load file .go same package

Tags: go, intellij-idea

I have the problem running file main.go in Intellij.

[image: My structure project]

Main.go and Common.go same package main. I run Main.go in Intellij then consle log display message error: ".\Main.go:9: undefined: showMsg".
showMsg is a function of Common.go

Comment: Check the run configuration. You are probably running a single file, and you should be running the whole package

Answer (score 3):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko-wKntCLjg) should show you how to solve the problem. You basically need to use a Run Configuration of type Go Application and use a Package kind not File kind.

Comment: I change Run kind to Package and Package is main. But have error Cannot find package 'main'

Comment: You don't need the package "main". As in the video, the package name should be the fully qualified package name. For example, if your main is under github.com/dlsniper/demo then that's the package you need to use, github.com/dlsniper/demo, not main.

Comment: If don't setting Package Run Configuration error "Package is not specified". It can still save but can not run

Comment: Sorry, I tried again, although there are errors of Run Configuration but successful Run successful. Thanks @dlsniper

Comment: If you pause the video at exactly [this frame][1] it should show you how to configure the run configuration exactly so that you don't see any error in the run configuration itself

    [1]: https://youtu.be/ko-wKntCLjg?t=50

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `go run main.go` from IntelliJ, so it doesn't look for `showMsg()` in other files.

You should execute `go build` instead, so that all of the files in the `main` package would be compiled into a single binary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `go.mod` file in the root directory of your project with the following contents:

   ```golang
   module mypackage
   ```
2. In your run configuration select "Run kind: Package" and "Package path: mypackage".

Feel free to change `mypackage` to your own package name.